# parallel search in CUDA

Tags: search, cuda, parallel-processing

Are there any CUDA methods/approaches/libraries for search operation, say a integer in an array of million entries ? More of a parallel search approach..

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple of references:

1) [GPU Gems, Chapter 37. A Toolkit for Computation on GPUs](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems/gpugems_ch37.html) (look for section 37.3.2 Binary Search)

2) [Parallel Search On Video Cards](http://www.usenix.org/event/hotpar09/tech/full_papers/kaldeway/kaldeway_html/)

Answer (score 0):

[Thrust](http://code.google.com/p/thrust/) library provides binary_search function.